# how to convert audio into signals

Tags: java, audio

how can I convert .wav file to signals in java ?

Comment: `MySignalHandler.Convert("/path/to/wavefile.wav")`. The implementation details of `MySignalHandler` are trivially obvious, and left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: What is trivally obvious ? If they are, please copy paste here and so do I learn

Answer (score 3):

Audio is a signal. Now how to read that signal from a wave file is another question.

- You can write your own decoder by following the [specifications](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html)
- Use java's [audioInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html) to read the audio stream

Please try to phrase your questions better in the future and use google more.

Comment: yes you are right, I have to ask my questions more clearly, I want to apply low pass filter to the audio, but I have to get float values from it. The conversion from bytes to the float values maybe wrong way. So I asked above question.

Comment: I don't know much about WAV formats, but isn't the byte that you get just the strength of that signal at that point in time. Basically you get the format, get how many bits are used in each sample and divide the signal by the 2^n where n is the number of bits. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SoX (the Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs) to convert audio file to text file with numeric values corresponding to sound frequency/volume.

Not sure if thats what you need.

Here is a link to the project: http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage